# Joining two SQL statements in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would I join both of these statements together so it comes up as one? The two counts are being done separately as it is coming from two different tables.

```
SELECT ril.invoice_label_id, ril.invoice_label, ril.invoice_label_code,
fp.price as fee, count(*) as ct, l.link_id
FROM consultation_chl c
INNER JOIN link_service_pct_location l on l.link_id=c.link_id
INNER JOIN medication m ON c.consult_id=m.consult_id
INNER JOIN ref_invoice_label ril ON m.formulary_id = ril.formulary_id
INNER JOIN pharmacy ph ON ph.pharmacy_id = l.id AND l.location_type_id = 3
INNER JOIN formulary f ON f.formulary_id=m.formulary_id
INNER JOIN formulary_price fp ON fp.formulary_id=f.formulary_id
WHERE l.pct_id = 1425
AND l.service_id = 4
AND c.invoice_period = '2015-04-30'
AND ril.section_id=2
AND ril.invoice_label_code in ('MEDTABS','MEDCAPS','DOXYCAPS','DOXYTABS')
AND fp.valid_from <= c.consult_date
AND (fp.valid_to >= c.consult_date OR fp.valid_to IS NULL) GROUP BY ril.invoice_label_id, ril.invoice_label, ril.invoice_label_code,
fp.price, l.link_id

SELECT ril.invoice_label_id, ril.invoice_label, ril.invoice_label_code,
ricf.fee, count(*) as ct, l.link_id
FROM consultation_chl c
INNER JOIN link_service_pct_location l on l.link_id=c.link_id
INNER JOIN medication m ON c.consult_id=m.consult_id
INNER JOIN ref_invoice_label ril ON m.formulary_id = ril.formulary_id
INNER JOIN pharmacy ph ON ph.pharmacy_id = l.id AND l.location_type_id = 3
INNER JOIN formulary f ON f.formulary_id=m.formulary_id
INNER JOIN formulary_price fp ON fp.formulary_id=f.formulary_id
INNER JOIN ref_invoice_consult_fee ricf ON ricf.invoice_label_id = ril.invoice_label_id
WHERE l.pct_id = 1425
AND l.service_id = 4
AND c.invoice_period = '2015-04-30'
AND ril.section_id=2
AND ril.invoice_label_code in ('MEDSUSP15-25','MEDSUSP16-35','MEDSUSP26-35','MEDSUSP36-45','MEDSUSP45+')
AND fp.valid_from <= c.consult_date
AND (fp.valid_to >= c.consult_date OR fp.valid_to IS NULL) GROUP BY ril.invoice_label_id, ril.invoice_label, ril.invoice_label_code,
ricf.fee, l.link_id
```

Comment: Show use the structure of the tables involved.

Comment: Join how? Make a short and simple example of what you want to do!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the UNION operator.

[SQL UNION Operator at W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Answer (score 0):

As your selected columns each have same names
you should be able to concatenate the selects with a "UNION" keyword in between.